# How can I make a Font Awesome Icon Stop spinning on Click?

Tags: animation, fonts, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I want this arrow to spin when the page loads and then when someone clicks on it, it pause the animation. How can I do that?

`<i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up fa-7x fa-spin"></I>`

Comment: use js. onclick remove class `fa-spin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO Morgan.

To achieve this you will want to use the following JavaScript to stop the icon spinning:

```js
function stopSpinning() {
  var element = document.getElementById("arrowIcon");
  element.classList.remove("fa-spin");
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i id="arrowIcon" class="fa fa-car fa-spin" onclick="stopSpinning()"></i>
```

Note that I have used `fa` and `fa-car` in my example because this is a FontAwesome icon that will run in the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it inline without creating any functions:

```
<i id="arrowIcon" class="fa fa-car fa-spin" onclick="this.classList.remove('fa-spin')"></i>
```